# Signing assembly - key seems to always be copied to project directory?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, code-signing

We have a signing key saved as a file for our assemblies. It seems when I create a new project for an assembly, and select this file to sign with, a copy is taken from the central location to the project directory.

Is this normal/desired behaviour? I am not familiar with it but that seems to suggest we'll end up with loads of copies in source control. I can see one project has a relative path set, but when I try to do this, it copies the file.

Comment: Those files should be small and immutable. Not a big problem.

Comment: Also, your source control should have a way to ignore files.

Comment: Presumably the signing is done at build-time though, so what if we want to sign using a new key... still annoying just to know you're not in control! @Eris yes but then the file won't be there at build-time on the build-server...

Comment: Since you said it's taken from a central location, I thought the file would be available at build time in the same way.

Comment: @Eris Yes. But the project properties are referencing a file in the project's directory. So how's it going to know to use the central file at build time - it'll just see a missing file surely?